# Verify Signature using JWT ( java-jwt)

Tags: java, jwt

I have to verify signature using java-jwt library, I have token and public key and public key starts from ssh-rsa AA...............
And I have to use RSA256 Algorithm, When I checked github I found following

```
Algorithm algorithm = Algorithm.RSA256(publicKey, privateKey);
JWTVerifier verifier = JWT.require(algorithm)
    .withIssuer("auth0")
    .build(); //Reusable verifier instance
DecodedJWT jwt = verifier.verify(token);
```

But my public key in form of String, and I dont have private key.. Please suggest me how to verify signature.

Answer (score 16):

When using asymmetric key encryption we need private key to create signature and public key to verify.
Coming to your question

**1. Private is not present**

Its fine, **you need not have private key to verify a signature** . Regarding the lib you are using , its variable args . It means you can just pass one depending on signing/verifying . Below is the java method where only public  key is used.

```
    public boolean verifyToken(String token,RSAPublicKey publicKey){
    try {
        Algorithm algorithm = Algorithm.RSA256(publicKey, null);
        JWTVerifier verifier = JWT.require(algorithm)
                //more validations if needed
                .build();
        verifier.verify(token);
        return true;
    } catch (Exception e){
        System.out.println("Exception in verifying "+e.toString());
        return false;
    }
}
```

**2. Public key is in string format, not in java PublicKey format.**

You need a mechanism to **convert** your public key string file to Java PublicKey format. Below is one method I can suggest.

```
    public static RSAPublicKey getPublicKeyFromString(String key) throws 
    IOException, GeneralSecurityException {

    String publicKeyPEM = key;

    /**replace headers and footers of cert, if RSA PUBLIC KEY in your case, change accordingly*/
    publicKeyPEM = publicKeyPEM.replace("-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----\n", "");
    publicKeyPEM = publicKeyPEM.replace("-----END PUBLIC KEY-----", "");

    byte[] encoded = Base64.decodeBase64(publicKeyPEM);
    KeyFactory kf = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
    RSAPublicKey pubKey = (RSAPublicKey) kf.generatePublic(new X509EncodedKeySpec(encoded));

    return pubKey;
    }
```

Comment: which maven dependency are you using for this example?

Comment: @Pep its  [jawa-jwt](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.auth0/java-jwt)

Answer (score -1):

This seems like a flaw/limitation of the https://github.com/auth0/java-jwt where it seems like you need both the public and private key to verify the signature. There isn't any need to have the private key when verifying the JWT using RSA256 algorithm.

This alternate java lib for dealing with JWT: https://github.com/jwtk/jjwt#reading-a-jws doesn't have the same limitation and hence I would recommend using it instead.

```
Jwts.parser()    
  .setSigningKey(publicKey) // <---- publicKey, not privateKey  
  .parseClaimsJws(jwsString);
```

Comment: From [java-jwt docs](https://github.com/auth0/java-jwt): "When using RSA or ECDSA algorithms and you just need to sign JWTs you can avoid specifying a Public Key by passing a null value. The same can be done with the Private Key when you just need to verify JWTs."

Answer (score -2):

If you are the Token generator you must be having a Private Key used to generate the Token.

You cannot verify the Token unless you have the Private key.

If you are consuming the Token at client side then you don't have the need to verify it.

In case you just want to verify the Token before writing the functionality you can go to:

https://jwt.io/

And it would be helpful if you go through this:

https://github.com/jwtk/jjwt

If someone is requesting the resource at Server you can do:

```
try {

    Jwts.parser().setSigningKey(key).parseClaimsJws(compactJws);

    //OK, we can trust this JWT

} catch (SignatureException e) {

    //don't trust the JWT!
}
```

I hope this helps...

Comment: This response is correct. IF you need to verify the JWT client side, you are using the wrong technology. The JWT contains a _backend_ state, but the client is requested to hold the state. This makes the backend stateless, and any virtual backend server can handle any request since the backend state is incorporated in each request (in the JWT). If you need data from a backend and you need to verify and ensure that a specific backend provided that data, https should be enough.

Comment: @AndreasLundgren Thanks.

Comment: Isn't the whole point of public/private key based signature algorithm that anyone should be able to verify the signature, without the private key?! Don't see why the token can't be verified without private key. This can be done in the node.js lib https://github.com/auth0/node-jsonwebtoken#jwtverifytoken-secretorpublickey-options-callback and seems like a flaw/limitation of the specific java lib implementation https://github.com/auth0/java-jwt that is referenced in the OP.